# lim and limsup equality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

Let $a_n$ be a positive, bounded sequence with $n \in \mathbb N$. We know that $\forall n \in \mathbb N,\limsup_{n \rightarrow+\infty} a_n \le a_n$.

Is it true that $\lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty} a_n=\limsup_{n \rightarrow+\infty} a_n$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes it is true, just apply $\lim inf$ on both sides of your inequality.

Comment: Taking $\liminf$ at the 2 sides may prove the equality for bounded sequence. But does it remain true for unbounded sequences?

Comment: Do you know what $\lim\sup$ is?